# ISecureDataFormat class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I see, that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect uses `ISecureDataFormat` for hold OIDC `state` parameter to verify it in callback endpoint in `HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()` method. I can't find any documentation for `ISecureDataFormat` class, but I'm too have to hold `state` parameter after handle 401 status code, also for verify it in callback. I don't want to use something what I don't understand, but as I said I can't find any documentation for this class, so I don't know how I can properly hold `state` parameter for verify it in callback. So, how `ISecureDataFormat` works and is it really this class that can be responsible for holding the `state` parameter? Here is the code which uses this class. It's at 459 and 805 line: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7e20302e2ff013fb21fe6206c5ac9b6fcb76d696/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs

Answer (score 0):

You could read the two documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.statedataformat?view=aspnetcore-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.isecuredataformat-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0

You could find the definition of `OpenIdConnectOptions.StateDataFormat` Property in the first document:
public `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISecureDataFormat<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties> StateDataFormat { get; set; }`

Then search the ISecureDataFormat intereface in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` NameSpace and you could find it in the second document

I think the two methods are  used to do something like encrypt/decrypy the AuthenticationProperties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0